# Array Manipulation hackerrank problem in java (getting Time limit error)

Tags: java, optimization

I am practicing programs in Hackerrank and the first Hard problem I tried I hit Time Limit error for few test cases. This is not a new thing for me and happened many times in the past during coding assessment tests. I however don't see how I can optimize this further. I need help regarding optimizing the current problem and someone please explain to me what I should do in order to come up with optimizations myself (for a begineer level atleast where I can pass basic coding tests time limits in Hackerranks and assessment exams like TCS).

Here's the link to the Hackerrank problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/problem

And this is my solution:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    
      static long arrayManipulation(int n, int[][] queries, int m) {
          
          long arr[]= new long[n];
          
          long ans=0;
          for(int i=0;i<n;i++) //initializing zero-array (Is this necessary?)
              arr [i]=0;

            for(int i=0;i<m;i++) // for each operation
            {
                for(int j=queries[i][0];j<=queries[i][1];j++) //add given k value from index a and b 
                {
                    arr[j]=arr[j]+ queries[i][2];
                }
                
            }
            Arrays.sort(arr);

           return arr[n-1];
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt(); //zero-array length
        int m=sc.nextInt(); // no of operations
        
        
        int queries[][]=new int[m][3];
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
            {
                queries[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
                queries[i][j]-=1; //-1 cause the problem specified 1-index so I'm subtracting 1 from 1st 2 inputs
            }
            queries[i][2]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        
        long result = arrayManipulation(n, queries,m);
        System.out.println(result);
        
        
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hackerrank challenges are less about writing code, and much more about finding the correct algorithm, to reduce the Big-O of the solution.

For this, your code is *O(n·m)*, since worst case is that all `m` operations are from `1` to `n`.

Correct solution is *O(m·log(m))*, which you can achieve by ignoring `n` and throwing away `arr`.

With that **hint**, hopefully you'll figure it out.

Comment: I'm sorry but I've been thinking about it and I can't seem to find any way to do that. Are you sure it will be O(m) (not O(n)) because as you said the worse case is that a and b are 1 and n, so you have to add n elements m times and I don't see how I can ignore n or throw the arr here. Some more input or hint would be appreciated :)

Comment: @bha_1999 Two examples, using syntax `a-b=k` for each query: 1) `n=10, m=3: 1-10=3, 2-9=4, 3-8=9` giving result 16. --- 2) `n=1000, m=3: 1-1000=3, 2-999=4, 3-998=9` giving result 16. --- As we can see, `n` has no meaning for the result, and calculating the maximum value doesn't require us to perform 1000+999+998 = 2997 addition operations. We can easily calculate the maximum value in our head, so how did we do that? Think about that, because that might be how we could code it too.

Comment: @bha_1999 Personally, when I posted a solution for that HackerRank challenge, I implemented it as a handling of events. Each query is two events, one increasing the value, and one decreasing the value. I found that simpler to code than some range-overlay algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You have to avoid using second `for` loop. With some precalculation, you can reduce complexity to `O(n·log(n))`.

```
static long arrayManipulation(int n, int[][] queries) {
    long[] arr = new long[n];

    for (int[] query : queries) {
        int a = query[0];
        int b = query[1];
        int k = query[2];

        if (k > 0) {
            arr[a - 1] += k;

            if (b < arr.length)
                arr[b] -= k;
        }
    }

    long max = arr[0];
    long cur = arr[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        cur += arr[i];
        max = cur > max ? cur : max;
    }

    return max;
}
```